# R time interval data type

Tags: r, types, timedelta

Is there a time interval data (variable) type in R? I have a CSV file with datetime and timeinterval columns. The data type of the datetime column can be `POSIXlt`, but I don't know how to set a timeinterval data type for the other column. Is it possible, or what is the best way to handle time inervals in R?

The time interval values in my CSV file looks like this [`<number of days> %H:%M:%S`]:

```
'0 20:32:59'
```

In Python pandas, there is a `timedelta64[ns]` data type for time intervals.

Thank you!

Comment: See [strptime](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) and [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html)

Comment: I've tried `strptime('0 20:32:59', format='%d %H:%M:%S')` but it returns with `NA`

Comment: in R You also need to have month and year in order for `strptime()` to recognize this as a date. And there is no date zero so that is going to confuse R

Comment: Thank you! In my CSV, the timeinterval column can be eg. `'366 20:32:59'` that means a duration of 1 year + 1 day + 20 hours... Of course if there where a leap year than this duration is only 1 year + 0 days + 20 hours (but it is not a problem because it is a time duration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the strings into the number of days and the time, using `stringi`, then use `lubridate` to manipulate the components.

```
library(stringi)
library(lubridate)
```

In the following example:

- `([0-9]+)` means capture one or more digits.
- `+` means one or more spaces (not captured).
- `([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})` means capture 2 digits, a colon, 2 digits, another colon, and 2 more digits.

`x <- "0 20:32:59"
matches <- stri_match_first_regex(x, "([0-9]+) +([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})")`

The number of days is the second column, and the hours/minutes/seconds are in the third column.

`days` creates a period of the number of days; `hms` creates a period of hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
n_days <- days(as.integer(matches[, 2]))
time <- hms(matches[, 3])
```

Now your total is just `n_days + time`, though presumably you want this relative to some origin, for example:

```
Sys.time() + n_days + time
```

Comment: Strictly, `days` and `hms` create *Period* objects, not *duration* objects. A Period of 1 day added to any time is always going to be the same time on the next day. A duration of 1 day (`duration(days=1)`) added to any time is going to be 86400s later, so might be different if there's a leap second.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see `? difftime`

If your csv is already split into columns, apply `as.difftime` to one and `as.POSIXlt` to the other.

For example:

```
as.difftime(0, units="days") + as.POSIXlt("20:32:59", format="%H:%M:%S")
```

[Edit]
If the entire result is to be an interval, this would do it:

```
as.difftime(0, units="days") + as.difftime("20:32:59", format="%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the `class()` of your result is `POSIXlt`; and the value of the result is `"2016-08-12 20:32:59 CEST"`. I think the class of `as.difftime(0, units="days")` colud be the winning data type, but I don't know how to tell to `difftime()` to recognize my data...