# Adding local tibble to Postgres database where a column is an interval

Tags: r, postgresql, dbplyr

I'm attempting to add an entry to a Postgres table where one of the columns is an interval. However, I'm unsure how to cast a local tibble's column type as an interval. As you might imagine, type differences make for unhappy databases. Any way to resolve this?

```r
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)

con <- my_db_con

df1 <- tibble(my_interval = "P3D")

df2 <- tbl(con, sql("select 'P3D'::interval as my_interval"))

# Will error:
rows_upsert(df2, df1, copy = TRUE)
```

The resultant error:

```plaintext
Matching, by = "my_interval"
Error: Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = interval
LINE 9:       WHERE ("LHS"."my_interval" = "RHS"."my_interval")
                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Add the complete error message as update to question.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38921338/7742981) answer suggests the use of `as.difftime` to create a column of type `difftime` which is probably as close as you will find to the SQL interval data type.

Comment: But, how is the string `"P3D"` an interval? You might need to recalculate these using `lubridate`.

Comment: @Simon.S.A. `"P3D"` is an interval in ISO8601 (as far as I know), and is an input format for Postgres - [see here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT). I don't know if `as.difftime` is what I'm looking for, since `difftime` usually requires some kind of definite start and/or stop period, which I do not have.

Comment: @Simon.S.A.. `select 'P3D'::interval;  3 days`. It is `ISO 8601` format per @ KaiAragaki link posted in comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (hopefully) fixed this in the dev version of dbplyr. Try it out via `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dbplyr")`. If this does not work please let me know.
There are two other possibilities for you to avoid this issue:

1. Explicitly copy the table and pass the column types via the `types` argument

```r
copy_to(my_db_con, df1, types = c(my_interval = "interval"))
```

2. You can explicitly copy and then use `mutate()`

```r
df2_copied <- copy_to(my_db_con, df1) %>% mutate(my_interval = sql("my_interval::interval"))

rows_upsert(df1, df2_copied)
```